# How to organize sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

this is more of a question of theory than anything else. I am writing an android app that uses a pre-packaged database. The purpose of the app is solely to search through this database and return values. Ill provide some abstract examples to illustrate my implementation and quandary. The user can search by: "Thing Name," and what I want returned to the user is values a, b, and c. I initially designed the database to have it all contained on a single sheet, and have column 1 be key_index, column 2 be name, column 3 be a, etc etc. When the user searches, the cursor will return the key_index, and then use that to pull values a b and c.

However, in my database "Thing alpha" can have a value a = 4 or a = 6. I do not want to repeat data in the database, i.e. have multiple rows with the same thing alpha, only separate "a" values. So what is the best way to organize the data given this situation? Do I keep all the "Thing Names" in a single sheet, and all the data separately. This is really a question of proper database design, which is definitely something foreign to me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There's a thing called database normalization http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization. You usually want to avoid redundancy and dependency in the DB entities using a corresponding design with surrogate keys and foreign keys and so on. Your "thing aplpha" looks like you want to have a many-to-many table like e.g. one or many songs belong/s to the same or different genres. You may want to create dictionary tables to hold your id,name pairs and have foreign keys referencing these tables. In your case it will be mostly a read-only DB so you might want to consider creating indexes with high `FILLFACTOR` percentage don't think sqlite allows it to do though. There're many ways to design the database. Everything depends on the purpose of DB. You can start with a design of your hardware like raids/file systems/db block sizes to match the F-System's block sizes in order to keep the I/O optimal and where to put your tablespaces/filegroups/indexes to balance the i/o load. The whole DB design theory/task is really a deep subject which is not to be underestimated nor is a matter of few sentences in the answer of stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score 0):

without understanding your data better here is my guess at what you are looking for.

```
table: product
- _id
- name

table: attribute
- product_id
- a
```